# How can I refresh a page automatically after a button has been clicked?

Tags: python, html, django, sqlite

I'm working on a housing project with a listing model. Listing has a ManyToManyField called favorites, which is supposed to hold all the usernames of users that clicked the favorite button on the detail page for the listing. Right now the favorite button adds the username to the listing's favorites, but then 404s because I'm not correctly redirecting to the listing detail page.

I've been trying to follow this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VoWw1Y5qqt8) and though I think I have followed correctly, my page 404s while in the tutorial, it refreshes (around 6:30).

Here is models.py:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    favorites = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='favorites', 
        blank=True)
...
```

listing_detail.html:

```
...
<form action="{% url 'favorite_listing' %}" method="listing">
  <button type="submit" name="listing_id" value="{{ listing.id }}" 
    class="btn btn-primary">Favorite</button>
</form>
```

urls.py:

```
...
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^favorite/$', views.favorite_listing, name="favorite_listing"),
]
```

views.py:

```
...
def favorite_listing(request):
    listing = get_object_or_404(Listing, 
        id=request.POST.get('listing_id'))
    listing.favorites.add(request.user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(listing.get_absolute_url())
...
```

As of now I'm getting:

> Page not found (404)
>   Request Method:    GET
>   Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/favorite/?listing_id=48
>   Raised by: reviews.views.favorite_listing

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what version of Django are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
`return redirect(reverse(your-route))`